# Block access to specific WebMethod using IIS Request Filtering

Tags: asp.net, iis, requestfiltering

I have a website where I can't change the deployed code. However I can access the IIS it is running under.

I want to block one specific Web Method. I thought I could probably do this using IIS Request Fitering by adding a `hiddenSegment` or `denyUrl` - however this does not seem to be effective. URLRewrite is not installed.

Example endpoint from IIS logs :

```
2022-11-30 03:34:59 10.63.194.247 POST /webService.asmx/WebMethodToBlock - 80 MYDOMAIN\userid 10.240.41.95 PostmanRuntime/7.24.1 - 200 0 0 3951
```

I have tried add "WebMethodToBlock" as both a denyUrl and a hiddenSegment - but requests are still handled by IIS.

It may be pertinent that the WebMethod is a POST. I can't seem to establish from the docs whether denyUrl and hiddenSegment rules only apply to GETs?

Comment: Try not to waste your time on IIS request filtering. IIS URL Rewrite module supersedes it in many ways.

Comment: Yes I did actually manage to install URL Rewrite and it is doing what I want. I just found the Request Filtering module frustrating in how it seemed as though it would do exactly what I wanted, but didnt.

Answer (score 0):

If you want block all request with Post, just add this:

[image]

There isn't an obvious way to block a single page form POST on IIS.
May be you can try a trick that POST method comes with a query sign "?"  after the URL.

[image]

Comment: Yes I figured this setting would block all POSTs - however this would totally break the application. It is only one single POST WebMethod which I want to block.

Comment: I edited my answer, you can try it.